# Two columns layout

Tags: html, css

Here is my version:

```
<div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left;display:inline-block;">
        123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:200px;">
        abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EV6xF/

All works fine untill text is small:

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: `All works fine untill text is small` is not a correct statement, its if `All works fine until a string is without any space`, use `word-wrap: break-word;` and you are good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `word-wrap:break-word;` to your CSS rule.

```
<div style="width:200px;float:left;display:inline-block;word-wrap:break-word;">
```

**[(Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/EV6xF/2/)**

Comment: That would be correct if “123 456” can be treated as equivalent to “123456”. Is the actual data a string that can be validly broken at any point?